# R - Find all the combinations of varying sizes with other variables present

Tags: r

I have a dataset of dates, names, and reasons. I need to find the most common combination of reasons that occur (by date / person).

In the example data below, I want the result to look like this or something similar:

- 12345 & 67890 occur together 2 time(s)
- 46512, 67890, 98732, 45612 occur together 1 time(s)
- 67890, 98732, and 12345 occur together 1 time(s)
- 12345 & 98732 occur together 1 time(s)

The order they occur in does not matter, just that they happen on the same date for the same person. If 4 reasons happen on a day then I don't want to count it as a combination of 2, 3, and 4 reasons - just 4. I'm completely stumped how to go about it.

Example data:

```
Date <- c("2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-03","2022-01-03","2022-04-06","2022-04-06", "2022-04-06","2022-03-04","2022-03-04","2022-03-04","2022-03-04","2022-02-07","2022-02-07")
Reason <- c("12345","67890","12345","67890","45612","67890", "98732","45612","67890", "98732","12345","12345","98732")
Person <- c("A","A","B", "B", "C", "C", "C","D","D","D","D","E","E")

data <- data.frame(Date, Person, Reason)
data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R version with the same premise as [@GeorgeSavva's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77916243/3358272) above.

```r
aggregate(Reason ~ Person, data = data, FUN = function(z) toString(sort(z))) |>
  subset(select = -Person) |>
  transform(N = ave(Reason, Reason, FUN = length)) |>
  unique()
#                       Reason N
# 1               12345, 67890 2
# 3        45612, 67890, 98732 1
# 4 12345, 45612, 67890, 98732 1
# 5               12345, 98732 1
```

Or with dplyr 1.1.0 or newer:

```r
library(dplyr)
data |>
  summarize(Reason = toString(sort(Reason)), .by = Person) |>
  count(Reason)
#                       Reason n
# 1 12345, 45612, 67890, 98732 1
# 2               12345, 67890 2
# 3               12345, 98732 1
# 4        45612, 67890, 98732 1
```

If older than 1.1.0, use

```r
data |>
  group_by(Person) |>
  summarize(Reason = toString(sort(Reason))) |>
  ungroup() |>
  count(Reason)
```

(I make no assertion that these are better or faster than the `data.table` solution, just alternatives.)

If uniqueness is a concern, you can always include `unique`, as in `toString(unique(sort(z)))`.

Comment: When I use the dplyr solution, I get this: > data %>% 
+   summarize(Reason = toString(Reason), .by = Person) %>%  # dplyr_1.1.0 or newer for .by=
+   count(Reason)
                                                                                     Reason  n
1 12345, 67890, 12345, 67890, 45612, 67890, 98732, 45612, 67890, 98732, 12345, 12345, 98732 13

Comment: What version of dplyr do you have? If older than `dplyr_1.1.0`, then `data |> group_by(Person) |> summarize(Reason=...) |> ungroup() |> count(Reason)`. See my edit, @Indescribled

Comment: I had to also group by the date and then manually count combinations in a different order (12345, 67890) vs (67890, 12345) but it worked well since I only had about 25ish unique combinations in my real data. Thank you though, this worked really well with minor modifications!

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table`:

First, for each person and date make a string corresponding to the combination of reasons they reported.  Then count the number of times each combination is reported.

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(data)
>
> data[ , .(Combination=paste(sort(Reason), collapse=", ")), by=.(Person, Date)][ , .N , by=Combination]
                  Combination N
1:               12345, 67890 2
2:        45612, 67890, 98732 1
3: 12345, 45612, 67890, 98732 1
4:               12345, 98732 1
```

Comment: You just beat me with the **exact** same answer I came up with... Possible enhancement: set `Reason` as key in the `setDT(...)`, so it gets sorted on creating the data.table. Then you can drop the `sort()`-function.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach in base R could involve using tapply and unique

```
reasons_by_person <- tapply(data$Reason, data$Person, function(x) toString(sort(unique(x))))

# Count the occurrences for each unique combination
counts <- table(reasons_by_person)

# Create a data frame with Reason and N
result <- data.frame(Reason = names(counts), N = as.vector(counts), row.names = NULL)

# Print the result
print(result)
Reason N
1 12345, 45612, 67890, 98732 1
2               12345, 67890 2
3               12345, 98732 1
4        45612, 67890, 98732 1
```